# I am trying to obtain formula to increment cell by 11 rows for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Here is what I am doing:

```
=IF('unique stock'!C11<=0,'unique stock'!C11,"")
```

and this goes on...

```
=IF('unique stock'!C22<=0,'unique stock'!C22,"")
=IF('unique stock'!C33<=0,'unique stock'!C33,"")
=IF('unique stock'!C44<=0,'unique stock'!C44,"")
```

Here, I am incrementing each cell by 11 rows manually. Please tell me if there is any way to increment rows by 11 dynamically for each cell.

Comment: you need to use ArrayFormula

Answer (score 1):

In excel you could use the following for a cell reference that would start at C11 and Jump by 11 for each row copied down:

```
INDEX(C:C,ROW(A1)*11)
```

You just need to substitute it into your equation.

```
=IF(INDEX('unique stock'!C:C,ROW(A1)*11)<=0,INDEX('unique stock'!C:C,ROW(A1)*11),"")
```

I am not sure if Google Sheets performs the function in the same manner as excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN('unique stock'!C11:C44), 
                  IF('unique stock'!C11:C44<=0,
                     'unique stock'!C11:C44, ), ))
```

[image]